# How i can make one website with multiple ip address

Tags: apache2

I have 10 domains and they 're pointed to 10 different ip addresses.

I assigned 10 ip addresses to my server (with directadmin).

How i can create one host to run one website with 10 domain/10 ipaddresses differently by DirectAdmin interface or other method?

Comment: What does this have to do with PHP and MySQL?

Comment: What a complete waste of IP addresses, I'd say. There is no technical benefit - even no SEO effect.

Answer (score 1):

create a virtual host like

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerAdmin aman@amanvarshney.com
  DocumentRoot "/var/www/abc"
  ServerName abc.com
  ServerAlias www.abc.com
  ServerAlias www.cdf.com
  ServerAlias www.mcd.com
 </VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your HTTP requests specify which domain the request was made on, so the server & PHP etc cann see this and you can serve/answer appropriately.

Server may also need to be configured to bind to *all* those addresses, not just one specific address.